# Using a property control to use unique values in a column for a Spotfire calculated column

Tags: properties, calculated-columns, spotfire

I am creating a calculated column (C) that uses a column property which is set through unique values in a column (B) which itself is set through a column selector. When I change the the data in this Column B (and column type remains the same) my calculated column (C) is not being updated appropriately.  I know I am likely making a simple error but I can't figure it out.

Column B = [${Surface.Property}] #This property is set with a drop down menu where I choose which column (e.g., Column A or Column D (each have their own unique values but they are both strings)

Column C =
MostCommon(case when [Column B]="[${MyData}.{Column B}.{Surface.Selector}]" Then Min([Depth]) OVER (Intersect([Location],[Column B]))
else NULL
END) OVER (Intersect([Location]))

This series of calculations works perfect if choose Column A in the drop down menu "Surface.Property" which is use to set the column/values of Column B. However, when I change and select Column D as Surface.Property, the calculation no longer works. Im guessing this is the result of of "unique values" change but I'm not sure how to make this part of the calculation [Column B]="[${MyData}.{Column B}.{Surface.Selector}]", accept "new" values.

Any thoughts would help and hopefully this is somewhat clear!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it turns out I need to insert the column property into my calculated column As Value rather than As Text.